# Visualise a decision tree in Colaboratory

Tags: scikit-learn, visualization, google-colaboratory, decision-tree, dtreeviz

What is the best way to visualise a decision tree using Google Colab? The visualisations from 'dtreeviz' (e.g.[Github](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/tree/master)) are really neat, but when running something like

```
!pip install dtreeviz
```

and

```
from sklearn.datasets import *
from sklearn import tree
from dtreeviz.trees import *
```

followed by

```
classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
classifier.fit(cancer.data, cancer.target)
viz = dtreeviz(classifier,
              cancer.data,
              cancer.target,
              target_name='cancer',
              feature_names=cancer.feature_names, 
              class_names=["malignant", "benign"],
              fancy=False )  

viz.view()
```

I get

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg', '-o', '/tmp/DTreeViz_62.svg', '/tmp/DTreeViz_62'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Which could have something to do which Colab running via my g-drive?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `!apt-get install graphviz`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, thank you - I tried it now. Still no visualisation returned - but also now no error message.

Comment: Hah, we are getting there! Can you try `from IPython.core.display import display, HTML; display(HTML(viz.svg())`?

Comment: Gosh, top man for persisting. And...You've solved it!   I've added a ")" at the end of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

- Make sure `graphviz` is installed via `!apt-get install graphviz`
- You can get the created SVG via `viz.svg()`
- Wrap the output in IPython's `HTML` and then call `display` to show it in your notebook

  ```
  from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
  display(HTML(viz.svg()))
  ```

**Longer answer**

- dtreeviz `view()` creates a SVG file in your temp directory
- This file gets passed to the `graphviz` library which opens it depending on your OS
- Google colab is recognized as `linux` and it tries to open the SVG file via the default viewing application
- The last step leads to nowhere if you are not running the notebook locally (probably the Google server now has either a couple of open SVG images or some error messages)
- The code from the short answer just gets the SVG code without saving it and then displays it in the notebook